# Why is the clear() function noexcept while the destructor not?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, noexcept

I noticed that, in the allocator-aware containers interface, the standard requires that the `clear()` member function be `noexcept` while the destructor not. Furthermore, it appears a discrepancy in the case of some node-based containers, such as `std::forward_list` and `std::set`, since the `clear()` member function performs the same operation as the destructor. Is there any reason for this difference?

Comment: How did you determine that those destructors aren't noexcept? You know they default to `noexcept` unless you use `noexcept(false)`?

Comment: Here's also [`[res.on.exception.handling]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.exception.handling-3) that claims that all standard library destructors are `noexcept`.

Comment: It gets better, as for a vector `clear()` is noexcept, but `erase(begin(), end())` is not. :-)

Comment: Have you tried some code that has objects with throwing destructors, and how they work with `clear()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Destructors are [implicitly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) `noexcept` unless any of the member variable destructors or base class destructors have been marked with `noexcept(false)` or the destructor itself is explicitly marked with `noexcept(false)`.